# How to clone privately hosted gitolite repo

Tags: git

I am able to login via SSH but I am not able to clone to private hosted repo. http://git.linuxdrone.org/

```
hello ashwin, this is gitolite v2.2-20-g9590645 running on git 1.7.8.2
the gitolite config gives you the following access:
 R   W  LinuxDrone
 R      LinuxDroneResources
 R   W  OpenPilot
 R   W  gcs
 Connection to git.linuxdrone.org closed.
```

How do I clone this repo?

```
git clone git@git.linuxdrone.org
fatal: repository 'git@git.linuxdrone.org' does not exist
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not a repo, it's a server, which hosts four repos, and you would clone then separately:

`git clone git@git.linuxdrone.org:LinuxDrone.git`

...and so forth.